# Direct bus from Johannesburg Airport to Mbabane

Tags: buses, south-africa, jnb, swaziland

I'm heading to Mbabane shortly. I'm flying into Johannesburg and someone mentioned that there was a direct bus from Johannesburg Airport to Mbabane. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: There's also info on minibuses from Joburg airport to Mbabane here on [Does anyone have experience taking a kombi from Johannesburg to Mbabane?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38568/does-anyone-have-experience-taking-a-kombi-from-johannesburg-to-mbabane)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BAZ BUS](http://www.bazbus.com/) used to do one at some point, but it's more of a private backpacker/shuttle service than scheduled bus.

Any larger scheduled bus services to Swaziland will generally depart from town central, and for the adventurous I guess there would be minibus taxis from taxi ranks nearer the airport. Personally, unless you have a reasonable tolerance for adventure (and good insurance) they may not be ideal.

Car rental is likely to be the easiest, you can get a car with border clearance (remember to get the border clearance documents from the rental company) and a GPS satnav relatively cheaply. The drive isn't unpleasant, roads aren't too bad. It takes around 5 hours 30 minutes to drive from Johannesburg to Swaziland.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikitravel's Swaziland article:

> Most public transport bus services arrive in Mbabane or Manzini.
>   Smaller bus lines, or minibuses generally provide service to
>   Johannesburg, Durban or Cape Town in South Africa as well as Maputo in
>   Mozambique.
>
> Larger buses usually travel within the country and some stop at border
>   crossings, where passengers must connect with an onward journey,
>   unless a specific group booking is done to hire a big bus.
>
> For scheduled road transport there is the Swaziland based siyeSwatini
>   [TransMagnific](http://www.goswaziland.co.sz/), which provides transport to and from Swaziland
>   daily. Stops include the Johannesburg airport. The TransMagnific
>   mini-buses are customised for added comfort and safety, unlike the
>   public transport. However, they require that bookings and payments be
>   done at least a day prior to travel so that your meal can be ordered
>   and the selection for the movie can be determined for the +-4hour
>   trip.
>
> The South African [Baz Bus](http://www.bazbus.co.za/), an independent line targeting
>   backpackers, also makes regular stops via South Africa to various
>   hostels and hotels in Swaziland. When traveling into and out of South
>   Africa to and from Swaziland, this is the safest option. All
>   mini-buses into South Africa go directly to Johannesburg bus stations,
>   which can be dangerous.