# Does anyone have experience taking a kombi from Johannesburg to Mbabane?

Tags: international-travel, transportation, south-africa, africa, swaziland

I'll be arriving in the Johannesburg airport and I've been told to take a kombi from there to [somewhere where they have kombis to Swaziland] and then from there to Mbabane. Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a kombi from the airport to Swaziland (Mbabane and Manzini) for 400 rand

Answer (score 4):

Not kombi vans exactly, but [Go Swaziland](http://www.goswaziland.co.sz/) offers comfortable-looking minibus transport from Johannesburg direct to Mbabane, meaning you won't have to figure out how to change in the middle in some other town. They'll also stay with you through the border crossing.

[They have several pick up points available, including JNB airport](http://www.goswaziland.co.sz/transmagnific-an-international-passenger-transport-service-in-swaziland/bus-pick-up-points-between-swaziland-and-johannesburg/)

Comment: I've seen those, they're double the price of kombi vans apparently (for good reason I'm sure though). I'm currently seeing if there's anybody who can attest to the kombi van trip from Johannesburg to Mbabane. Specifically, how easy (or hard) it is and how safe (or unsafe) it is.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep looking as well